# EF join works but SelectMany doesn't

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Why does this work:

```
// find all second level categories
from c in Categories
where c.ParentId == null
join c2 in Categories on c.Id equals c2.ParentId
select c2
```

But the following throws a **System.NotSupportedException : Unable to create a constant value of type 'Category'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context**:

```
from c in Categories
where c.ParentId == null
from c2 in Categories
where c.Id == c2.ParentId
select c2
```

?

Note: what I'm really looking to do is join the table to itself using a join condition that includes a `like`:

```
from c in Categories
from c2 in Categories
where c.Lineage like c2.Lineage + '%'
select c
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from c in Categories
from c2 in Categories
where c.Lineage.StartsWith(c2.Lineage)
select c
```